# Is it possible to download songs from app to itunes library

Tags: iphone, itunes

I've seen a lot of questions out there looking to play music from the user's library on the app, or to access iTunes from the app to download things, but I'm looking to do the opposite. I'm creating an app for a local band, and they are supplying 5 full length songs to include in the app, and I thought it would be a nice touch to include an option to download the songs from the app into the users iTunes library (at the request of the user of course). Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. Apple doesn't want you in there, because you could have the ability to mess some things up. If you've ever used a ringtone app, they actually have you copy the ringtones onto your computer, and then reinsert them onto the device as a ringtone, because the app doesn't have access to the ringtone section, so you probably can't do that with songs. I know you don't want to hear this, but you're better off just putting the songs onto the iTunes Store and then putting a link in your app to the songs on iTunes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's kind of what I thought. That is an option, but I know they charge .99 for the song on iTunes, they just wanted a bonus for their fans who downloaded the app.

Comment: Maybe you could put the  songs on a website and let the user download them to their computer and then manually put the songs into iTunes? Or let them play the songs directly within the app using AV Foundation, but then the songs wouldn't be directly into iTunes. Those are the two best options. Good luck!